# Very new to jquery - why doesn't this work

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I simply want to shift the .icon to the right. trying to animate .icon by the amount of position().left

My code isn't working and I don't know why. I bet its very simple!!

```
<script>
$("li.menu-item").hover(function(){
    var pos = $(this).position().left;
    $(".icon").animate({left : pos+'px'}, 1500 );

});
</script>




</head>
<body>


<div id="menu-wrapper">
<ul id="main-nav">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Blog</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Sponsored</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">About</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="icon">move please</div>

</div><!-- //END menu-wrapper -->
</body>
```

css

```
#menu-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 50px; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;}

.icon {
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    background: url(../images/plus-menu.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    bottom: -4px;
}

#main-nav { line-height: 1.0; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; }

#main-nav{list-style: none;}

#main-nav li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #b2b2b2;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
}

#main-nav li { float: left; position: relative; }

#main-nav li a:hover, #main-nav li a:active { color: #404040; }
```

Any help will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum. With minimal modifications (`stop()`ping the animation on each new hover event, so stuff doesn't get chained), it seems to work in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Myfwn/).

Comment: Wow, you're honestly doing great!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("li.menu-item").hover(function(){
        var pos = $(this).position().left;
        $(".icon").animate({left : pos+'px'}, 1500 );

    });
});
</script>
```

Check this [beginner tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Hello_jQuery) out for more info

Comment: Damn. Didn't even occur to me that the ready event was missing. Cheers! +1

Comment: Hi thanks for that, but it still hasn't worked I can't see where I have gone wrong. Is the code ok/